# How can I read inputs from a Switch Pro Controller in Python?

Tags: python, controller, nintendo

So the long term plan is, to wirte a program, that can communicate with the nintendo switch and simulate inputs and more stuff through python script.
For that I need to know what inputs the switch pro controller sends to the switch (packages).
So I want to read out what the Pro Controller sends.
Do you guys have any ideas how that would be manageable ?

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking toward the right direction. But there is no need to re-invent the wheel unless for your own learning purpose.

To control Nintendo Switch with computer over Bluetooth check this:
https://github.com/mart1nro/joycontrol

For more reliable connectivity than Bluetooth (you would want wired connection if the goal is to leave your automation program to run for hours/days) you will need a little development board (Teensy++ 2.0 in this example):
https://github.com/bertrandom/snowball-thrower

Once the connectivity has been established with above solutions, you will be able to construct your upper level automation program to achieve your goal, such as:
https://github.com/carrotcn/turnip-fortune